# Parse a json coming from backend api

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a json coming from backend api as below :

```
{"roleIds": [1], "menuIds": [1,2,3]}
```

In the angular ui, am consuming the data as below :

```
$http.post(url,{userName:$scope.credential.email,password:$scope.credential.password}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                    $cookies.userData = data;
                                    $window.location.href = 'index.html';
                            })
```

How can i parse the $cookies.userData object to get the roleIds and menuIds?

Answer (score 0):

$cookies.userData = JSON.parse(data);
It will return an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cookies.userData = JSON.parse(data);
```

Then you can access it like:

```
$cookies.userData["roleIds"]
$cookies.userData["menuIds"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why `$cookies.userData` ?

You can assign it in normal `variable` or in `$scope` object and then parse it using **`dot (.)`** operator.

**DEMO**

```js
var userData = {"roleIds": [1], "menuIds": [1,2,3]}

console.log(userData.roleIds);
console.log(userData.menuIds);
```

Comment: My UI is a single page application using angular js. And I have used cookies to store the user information,so as to be accessible across the app. Using $scope will be bounded to a particular view and controller. Any alternative to this? suggestions?

Comment: You can use service to communicate across the application, between several controllers and views or you can use HTML5 localstorage if data is not so critical.

Comment: Yes service is a good approach. Can expose the data , through a function call from the created service.

Comment: Yes we can do..see this answer of mine .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537681/how-to-persist-web-api-data-in-angularjs/43538313#43538313